# SQL Server error: Violation of Primary Key - why?

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server is causing an error when I try to insert values at the same time to multiple rows one after another. So basically, I have created following table and query

```
create table Dates
(
     id int not null primary key, 
     dates DateTime Not Null Default(GetDate())
)

declare @i int 
set @i = @@ROWCOUNT + 1

insert into dbo.Dates(id)
values (@i + 1)

select * from Dates
```

When I run second query repeatedly, this error happens:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__Dates__3213E83F76720BE7'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Dates'. The duplicate key value is (3).
>   The statement has been terminated.

Why it is this error showing up? I am creating a form, information will be stored in SQL Server and I do not want this to happen. What can I do? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe gaps? Use some kind of autoincrement/identity column or whatever SQL Server calls it.

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry I am new to SQL

Comment: First, learn the basics of how databases work (you did say that you were new).  Second, let the database generate the id field for you.

Comment: ID Field is auto-increment. It updates itself whenever I run the query. Whenever I run the query, it updates with date/time stamp. I want database to add new ID field if I run the query in a row.

Comment: use [Identity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186775.aspx) `[id INT IDENTITY(1,1)  NOT NULL]`

Comment: "why is this error showing up" because you're trying to insert another record into the table with the same primary key...

Comment: @ humpy dumpty yes, I have created a new table with specified characteristics.
user2366842, I was using declare and rowcount and whenever I run the update statement in a row it was not incrementing and giving me the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [identity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) that will generate next value for your column automatically

```
create table Dates (
    id int identity(1,1) primary key, 
    dates DateTime Not Null Default(GetDate())
)
```

Comment: How can I alter the table to change to identity with increment? Thank you.

Comment: With this table definition you will not be able to insert a new record without explicitely giving a value for the `dates` column. An insert statement needs at least *one*  value that you want to insert.

Comment: @Invisible: altering a table column to "identity" is not really possible within SQL-Server. You will have to define a new table with the identity column and then copy the existing data over from the old table. This is what happens behind the scenes if you do it in the MSSQL-studio version.

Comment: thanks 
So basically I created a new table with IDENTITY and it is working now. @scsimon , you are right that client should not be seeing rows or know that is happening in the background. Thank you  everyone else who have helped me in this.

Comment: @cars10 you can do an insert statement with no explicit values. You would do something like this. INSERT INTO TableName DEFAULT VALUES

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [IDENTITY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx). No need to do this manually.

In your case, [@@ROWCOUNT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) doesn't change hence you get duplicate keys...

> Statements that make a simple assignment always set the @@ROWCOUNT value to 1. No rows are sent to the client. Examples of these statements are: SET @local_variable, RETURN, READTEXT, and select without query statements such as SELECT GETDATE() or SELECT 'Generic Text'.

```
declare @i  int 

set @i=@@ROWCOUNT+1
select @i
set @i = @@ROWCOUNT+1
select @i
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression `@i+1` in the insert statement will always return the same value. It doesn't increment the value of variable `@i`. That's why there is an error. Put  insert statement inside a loop and use statement `set @i = @i + 1` to increment the value of `@i` inside the loop.